# HorizontalPager Parameter "count" not found

Tags: android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose

I got an error that the parameter could not be found while using the Horizontal Pager.

[image]

[image]

My Compose Version is

```
"1.2.0-alpha03"
```

Kotlin Version is

```
"1.6.0"
```

This is the canonical code that puts the size of pages in the count in the parameter.

I don't know why. Please help me.

Comment: HorizontalPager is part of accompanist, not compose library itself, so what's the version of accompanist you use?

Answer (score 1):

You should know that **accompanist** is now **deprecated** and no longer supported and instead you should use **androidx.compose.foundation** which uses **pageCount** instead of **count**. Read this [Migration guidance](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) to understand more. Here is a quick fix

```
       val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { 3 })
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top) {

    }
```